# Access Zend_Registry from public directory?

Tags: zend-framework, phpbb3

I'm integrating phpBB3 into Zend Framework. The requirement is, the admin should be able to disable/enable it via `application.ini`. I actually tried including `Registry.php` in the `index.php` but it didn't work. What's the correct way to access `Zend_Registry` from the public directory? Or is it possible?

If you could give me an idea about how to load phpBB3 inside the application instead of public directory so that accessing `Zend_Registry` wouldn't be a problem, I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `application.ini`:

```
phpBB.active = true;
```

In `index.php`:

```
if ($application->getOption('phpBB')){
  //do something
}
```

Zend Registry should be available in `index.php` (after `$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);`, but will be empty as you didn't set anything yet.